# Как спарсить PDF в string?

Tags: php, парсер, pdf

уже перебрал некоторые парсеры. в основном они просто возвращают пустой результат.

https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser - этот парсер работает, однако в результате слова разбиваются на части ("сло во", "слов о", и т.д.), хотя это и зависит от самого документа.

есть ли еще какие-то проверенные решения? или же придется писать парсер самому?

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно использую: https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

```
use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;
$pdftext = Pdf::getText('book.pdf'); // Сохраняем в переменную текст PDF
```

Если у вас будут какие-то проблем с ним, то обратите внимание на опции. Возможно у вас иная кодировка файлов или ещё что-то мешает корректной работе.

Документация по опциям: 
https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext

А также на следующую возможную проблему:

> Some PDF files contain fonts whose encodings have been mangled beyond
>   recognition. There is no way (short of OCR) to extract text from these
>   files.

Ещё многие хвалят XPDF - https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html
Но с ним не работал.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать ocrmypdf c движком tesseract

https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Можно запускать как локально как сервис как контейнер.

Имеет поддержку около 100 языков.